# Django: Checkbox choice displaying as True/False value

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox, model

I'm a beginner at django and I'm trying to get my calendar to display a checkbox itself rather than a True/False value. I'm able to get the data to save from the form however

## models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    #end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    event_checked = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:event_edit', args=(self.id, ))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> <label> {self.title} {self.event_checked}<label></a>'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} by {}'.format(self.title, self.description, self.user)
```

## forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

 event_checked = forms.BooleanField()

  class Meta:
    model = Event
    # datetime-local is a HTML5 input type, format to make date time show on fields
    widgets = {
      'start_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
    }
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'start_time')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # input_formats parses HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
    self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
```

## views.py

```
def event(request, event_id=None):
    instance = Event()

    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    else:
        instance = Event()

    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        event = Event.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data, user=request.user)
        print(event.title)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:calendar'))
    return render(request, 'cal/event.html', {'form': form})
```

[How my calendar looks with some events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a89bZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that was your goal:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

 event_checked = forms.BooleanField()

  class Meta:
    model = Event
    # datetime-local is a HTML5 input type, format to make date time show on fields
    widgets = {
      'event_checked' forms.CheckboxInput(), # <-- added this 
      'start_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'),
    }
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'start_time')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # input_formats parses HTML5 datetime-local input to datetime field
    self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',)
```